# Did exams exist in universities in medieval times?

Tags: exams, academic-history

I'm not really sure if this is the right place for a question like this - but it seems the closest.

I was reading about exams on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exam

It makes it seem that the West did not really have exams until around the 1800's. To clarify, by exam I mean the ones we understand it to be today - standardised paper exams - but from what I'm reading, it doesn't seem there was even much of oral exams. There was a lot of push back from it's introduction from China in the late 1800's. Yet the West certainly did have universities that existed well before then.

So how did those universities, like Oxford for example, examine students? Was it all verbal? It seems strange to think of education without examination.

Comment: "It seems strange to think of education without examination." The modern focus on evaluation is what seems strange to me, when education should be about teaching, learning, sharing...

Comment: Keep in mind that industrial scale paper is a 19th century development.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Interesting question. The short answer is: yes, exams were oral (and in Latin!), but they were really more arguments or discussions than quizzes. Universities were smaller and the students and teachers knew one another well, so ultimately it was the teachers' opinions of each student, not a transcript, that mattered.

For the longer answer, we can start with Cambridge's [website](https://www.cam.ac.uk/about-the-university/history/the-medieval-university):

> The teaching took the form of reading and explaining texts; the examinations were oral disputations in which the candidates advanced a series of questions or theses which they disputed or argued with opponents a little senior to themselves, and finally with the masters who had taught them. Some of the masters, but by no means all, went on to advanced studies in divinity, canon and civil law, and, more rarely, medicine, which were taught and examined in the same way by those who had already passed through the course and become doctors.

So exams were mostly oral; undergrads would have to argue with grad students, and grad students would do the same with the doctors.

The situation in the early US appears to be similar. According to [Lester Hunt's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=cuT_EnGHM9wC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126):

> Initially, as at Harvard in 1646, exams were oral and aimed to assess nothing more than the amount of information the students had packed into their minds. Later, using written tests, student writing and reasoning skills were assessed as well. Eventually, exam by recitation would dwindle and disappear, lingering mainly in the dreaded doctoral "orals." According to Mary Lovett Smallwood's history of grading in five early colleges...the first known grading *system* comparable to ours was instituted at Yale in 1785...Essentially, it was a 4-point system using words rather than letters and numbers."

So again, mostly oral exams. It's worth remembering that these were smaller classes where the students would have personal relationships with the teachers over multiple years. So, exams leading to formal written grades were probably less important than the subjective opinions that the teachers would form. This is similar to graduate study or even seminary today -- there may be some "objective" graded written tests, but the student's reputation with the teachers (e.g., through letters of recommendation) is far more important.

It's also worth noting that when evaluating students (up until ~1830 or so), the criteria were not only academic. Behavioral conduct (e.g., keeping one's room tidy), social conduct, and chapel attendance were also explicit metrics to be considered (some discussion of this is [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40291918)).

Comment: Oh ok. So it seems that these were not standardised exams but rather a bit more whimiscal? If I felt like quizzing a boy on Newton's theory of gravitation today but the next boy on Huygen's theory of light it'd be fine? [Assuming they were studying physics]

Comment: Yes, probably not the same questions for each student. But Newtonian physics didn’t make it into the classroom right away; most of the content would still have been from the Greek and Roman “thinkers” (e.g., Aristotle)

Comment: The Cambridge page is about the time before Newton, and it describes the subjects they studied: "They studied first what would now be termed a 'foundation course' in arts - grammar, logic and rhetoric - followed later by arithmetic, music, geometry and astronomy, leading to the degrees of bachelor and master ... Some of the masters, but by no means all, went on to advanced studies in divinity, canon and civil law, and, more rarely, medicine." Some of this sounds Greek and Roman and some does not.

Comment: So, quite a lot like oral qualifying exams that are still common in doctoral education. Note that we didn't have mass education back then. Numbers were smaller. Written exams are most likely a result of the change in scale and the need to regularize/normalize outcomes.

Comment: Also note that in Medieval Times the "university" was more of an association of scholars than some legal entity. Low level "academics" even had to rent space in which to give lectures, IIRC, and would charge (sell tickets to) the audience.

Comment: @JohnHon I'd argue that the traditional oral exams (which were widely used in modern times and are still in use) tend to be much more thorough than standardized written exams - I'd rather consider that trying to guesstimate competency by a multiple choice test is totally whimsical compared to an oral examination, standardized written tests are effectively a workaround for cases where you can't afford to do proper individual evaluation due to large scale.

Comment: This is similar to how many guilds accepted new artisans. A master or a group of masters has a great deal of leeway in how they determine who is eligible, rather than having a set of standardized criteria.

Comment: @Buffy The largely increased number of students (or population, in general) is also a  major factor in introduction of objective measures for testing

Comment: @Buffy Universities might have developed out of student-teacher associations, but were recognized by royal/imperial charters quite soon: Bologna 1158, Paris 1200, Cambridge 1209, Salamanca 1218, Oxford 1248,... That doesn't mean they were fully financed, but it came with at least some grants, and more important to this question, with the right to grant a _licentia docendi_, the right to teach (theology). Since 1213 the University of Paris could grant a church-approved _licentia ubiquie docendi_, a right to teach anywhere.

Comment: @cag51 The "greek and roman thinkers" were only taught to undergraduate students (the [trivium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivium), leading to the baccalaureat examination). The main branches were theology, law and medicine. A _doctoral_ degree in liberal arts (to which the study of ancient thinkers belongs) only started to appear with the transformation of its faculties to faculties of philosophy in the 15th century.

Comment: Sure, agreed. My comment about the thinkers was intended only in response to the suggestion that medieval universities (or even early modern universities) would have been studying Newton or other early modern physics. Offhand, I don’t believe university physics went past Aristotle and such until the 1800s.

Comment: @cag51 The main reason medieval students didn't study Newtonian physics is that the medieval period ended in about 1485 and Newton was born in 1642

Comment: We do not disagree.

Comment: @JohnHon "So it seems that these were not standardised exams but rather a bit more whimiscal? If I felt like quizzing a boy on Newton's theory of gravitation today but the next boy on Huygen's theory of light it'd be fine?" This is not some strange, medieval way of doing things. This is exactly how exams worked during my bachelor's studies (Czechia, 2000's, Physics/Linguistics/Logic). They would sometimes have a written component too before an oral interview. This was considered entirely normal and noone would suggest that it is unfair to ask one student about Newton and another about Huygens.

Comment: @JohnHon The pursuit of / obsession with standardization and "objective" numbers (GPA's and such) is very much culturally dependent (and no doubt can be associated with the over-legalization of certain societies) rather than a matter of medieval vs. modern. Both approaches have their own advantages: making sure everyone has exactly the same conditions is a laudable goal, but having a 20 minute chat with a student will reveal far more about their understanding of the topic than a standardized exam.